# Press button on every swipe | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've made a simple piano app in Flutter where there are multiple adjacent buttons, each playing a different note/sound. I want the button's `onPressed: ()` method (or the code inside it) to work whenever the user's finger passes over that exact button's area (same for all buttons). The method should work each time even if the finger passes over the button **more than once in a single swipe**.
I've looked into the `GestureDetector class` but I don't think it quite achieves the multiple presses in a single swipe.
Any ideas how can I make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to try using the [Listener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html) widget.

By setting [PointerMoveEventListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/PointerMoveEventListener.html) you'll be able to perform different actions for each position of the pointer, but you'll have to map the position and sizes of each button.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out.
Just  wrap your key in a `MouseRegion` and call the `onTap` function on `onEnter`.

```dart
MouseRegion(
    onEnter: (event) {
        if(event.down){
        onTap!();
        }
        
    },
    child: InkWell(
      borderRadius: _borderRadius,
      highlightColor: Colors.grey,
      onTapDown: onTap!;

    ),
  )
```

This doesn't trigger the button or inkwell animation though. But this can be solved with a custom button.